# What's a word for someone you haven't seen in a long time?

Tags: single-word-requests, names

What's a word for someone that I haven't seen in a long time? I remember one person saying: "Oh, wow! I think I'm seeing a *ghost*. I can't believe it's you!" But I'm not so sure if "ghost" is right, given that seeing a ghost means "appearing to be very scared or shocked." Any suggestions are welcome! =)

Comment: A long-lost friend/relative.

Comment: I suppose. I'm pretty sure there is a specific word, though... =)

Comment: Just to point out “***looked** like he’s seen a ghost*” is scared or shocked.  But that’s not what’s happening here. Saying “I must be seeing a ghost” means “I see you but I (figuratively) thought you were dead because I hadn’t seen you in so long.  (Sometimes with the added nuance that being dead is the only acceptable reason for staying out of contact-  that a *good* friend would have been in touch before now)

Comment: Some people will say, “*Well hi stranger*” as a joking way to refer to someone they haven’t seen in a long time.  Especially when they think it’s the stranger’s fault for the long absence.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for your help! =)

Comment: “Whatsisname” ?

Comment: We say 'keep in touch : don't be a stranger'. When does someone cease to be an acquaintance and revert to being a 'stranger' ?

Answer (score -1):

How about the idiom **blast from the past**? From M-W:

> **[blast from the past](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blast%20from%20the%20past)**: a striking reminder of an earlier time : something that excites nostalgia

This is a broader term than meeting someone you haven't seen in a long time, but it captures perfectly the emotions one would feel upon doing so.

Example:

> Wow! Seeing you is a real **blast from the past**!